Constantly getting DEVELOPER_ERROR in Android Simulator using Firebase Authentication
I am completely stuck with the task of getting the Firebase Authentication to work locally on my simulator.
It used to work but due to an environment change I have to re-configure it.
By now, I have five-times checked if the SHA1 and SHA256 values in the Firebase project are correct.
SHA1:   90:3c:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:84 ￼
SHA256: 32:c2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:c1

From the google-service.json, I am taking the client_id which is corresponding witht the certificate_hash as such:
{
  "client_id": "12345667890-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_type": 1,
  "android_info": {
    "package_name": "com.example.development",
    "certificate_hash": "903cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx84"
  }
},

In my react-native app I am using the hard-coded value:
useEffect(() => {
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    scopes: ['email'],
    webClientId: '12345667890-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  });
}, []);

But I keep getting keep getting this DEVELOPER_ERROR without any additional information of what's actually the problem here.
I red somewhere, that we're not supposed to take this client id, instead I am supposed to take the "web" client ID (client_type: 3):
{
  "client_id": "1234567890-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_type": 3
}

but that didn't change anything.
Getting the SHA1 & SHA256 values
For my local build, I am running
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

which gives me the same result as running
cd android/ && ./gradlew signingReport


I recently had the same issue. Finally I found out that in the build.gradle file in android/app folder, under signingConfigs -> debug the keystore file did not match with the google-services.json I'm using.
Make sure to check these values:
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore android/app/debug.keystore

also, note, that you have to use the Web Client ID (client_type: 3) to make it work:
GoogleSignin.configure({
  scopes: ['email'],
  webClientId: environment.webClientId,
});


This was it.. maddening.. took half a day from me. I edited your answer a bit in order to complete the example. Thank you!
